# How can i host angular 5 in sub-domain of server

Tags: angular, angular5

When going to host in main server its working fine(ex: www.demo.com). the same files if going to host in (ex: app.demo.com ) it's not working perfectly. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you do ng build --prod on an Angular CLI project, you will get a dist/ folder containing a static HTML5+Javascript web page. You'll need to deploy the contents of that folder to a server configured properly to serve it.

You can find some more details in https://angular.io/guide/deployment. But whatever server you use, you must configure it properly yourself.